# how to recompile php with mysql when you installed php through rpm

Tags: php, compilation

I have upgrade PHP version to 5.3.2 on fedora core 6 system through RPM. Now php is working fine but Mysql is not associated with PHP.

When I checked phpinfo it says '--without-mysql' '--without-gd'  in configure command.

I tried running ./configure command which suppose to fire through source of php, but I've installed php through RPM, how do I find the source? ./configure command is not at all working.

Any alternative to recompile php with mysql if I install php through RPM.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'd remove the RPMs, and then rebuild from source.

To find out what RPMs are already installed, use the RPM query command in conjunction with grep to filter your results:

```
rpm -qa | grep -i php
```

To remove the RPMs listed, do:

```
rpm -e <filename>
```

for each RPM you found in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, whoever provides the PHP rpm will also provide a php-mysql or php4-mysql rpm. Look for it.

Comment: Hi Habbie, I installed the rpm 
# rpm -qa | grep -i php
php-common-5.1.6-3.7.fc6
php-snmp-5.1.6-3.7.fc6
php-ncurses-5.1.6-3.7.fc6
php-xmlrpc-5.1.6-3.7.fc6
php-mbstring-5.1.6-3.7.fc6
php-pear-1.4.9-4
php-gd-5.1.6-3.7.fc6
php-odbc-5.1.6-3.7.fc6
php-devel-5.1.6-3.7.fc6
psa-php5-configurator-1.3.0-fc6.build82070918.10
php-mysql-5.3.2-2.fc6.remi
php-pdo-5.1.6-3.7.fc6
php-cli-5.1.6-3.7.fc6
php-dba-5.1.6-3.7.fc6
php-pgsql-5.1.6-3.7.fc6
php-soap-5.1.6-3.7.fc6
php-xml-5.1.6-3.7.fc6
php-imap-5.1.6-3.7.fc6
php-bcmath-5.1.6-3.7.fc6
php-ldap-5.1.6-3.7.fc6
php-5.3.2-2.fc6.remi

Comment: but still no luck. I have restarted apache also. Do i need to do anything else?